# What genre is the song "Foots" by the band Stuff?

Tags: jazz, funk

Here I have the link the song *foots* by a band called *Stuff*

http://youtu.be/WcA0tJFoL20

What is the genre of this? Is it funk or pop?

Comment: I also think it belongs to funk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking Stuff up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuff_(band)), it seems as though they are a jazz-funk band. Listening to that track, I'd be inclined to say that that song is also jazz-funk, or at the very least instrumental funk. The album on which "Stuff" appears (also called [*Stuff*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuff_(Stuff_album))) was produced by a jazz drummer named Herb Lovelle, and a jazz/R&B producer named Tommy LiPuma, further supporting the jazz-funk categorization of the song.

Answer (score 2):

The opening segment of the track is heavily blues influenced but as it transitions it begins to have a bit of a funk groove to it.

Wiki: *"Stuff developed a danceable rhythm and blues and funk sound, the likes of which had not been heard since the days of the Harlem Swing Bands of the 40s and 50s.*"

Comment: Does the opening segment sound a lot like "Habbie Doobie" from Texas Gentlemen? Hard to think they weren't accidentally inspired by the Stuff song.

Answer (score 0):

In 1983 a very "similar" song was released by Jan Akkerman. Title: Pietons. He claimed the credits.